# Iterate over list in dictionary for one given key

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am trying to iterate over following dictionary

This is how dictionary looks like

```
B-> N, P
N -> B, S
S-> N
P -> X, Y, U, I, R
```

How can I iterate only on list of P's key so it should return X, Y, U, I, R?

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> vertices = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

Comment: What about for (var value in vertices["p"]) { ... } ? It'll iterate only over X, Y, U, I, R. Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
foreach (var item in vertices["P"])
{
     //handle item value here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> vertices = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
vertices.Add("B", new List<string> { "N", "P" });
vertices.Add("N", new List<string> { "B", "S" });
vertices.Add("S", new List<string> { "N" });
vertices.Add("P", new List<string> { "X", "Y", "U", "I", "R" });
vertices.TryGetValue("P", out List<string> value);
foreach (string s in value)
{
    Console.Write(s + ",");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would have been great to use [KeyValuePair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

So, your iteration would look like this:

```
var result = vertices.SingleOrDefault(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Key == "P");
List<string> list = result.Value;
list.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Comment: I am trying to find one specific value so this will iterate over every key value

Answer (score -1):

I would use LINQ for this:

```
KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> entry = vertices.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Key == "P");
foreach(string whatever in entry.Value)
{
     //your text is here
}
```

Comment: why the down vote?  You can pull whatever you want out of the yourAnswer variable....

Comment: Edited for clarity.  Please up vote if you find this helpful.